# Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed; tried varoius methods to solve the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I seem to be having a problem when I try to send an email to myself from Heroku. There have been a lots of other people with a similar issue, and I have attempted to incorporate the solutions that worked for them, but sadly, to no avail.

my
    `environment.rb` has the following code:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authenticaton => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV['SENGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',`enter code here`
    :enable_startstls_auto => true
}
```

When I try to test the page on Heroku, it is unsuccessful.

I ran

```
heroku logs
```

to try and determine the problem, and the only error I could see was

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
```

My mailer file doesn't have any issues. I am not sure what's wrong, and would appreciate some assistance!

edit:

I have tried

```
telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587
EHLO
AUTH LOGIN
Enter username in Base64
Enter password in Base64
```

but telnet cannot be found. Perhaps I am not understanding what must be done...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865596/rails-4-sendgrid-integration-giving-error-unauthenticated-senders-not-allowed

Comment: telnet does not seem to work. it says command not found.